# What do employers focus on when examining the CV of a PhD graduate when applying for a Post Doc?

Tags: postdocs, stem

What is the thing you look for (and reject when not found) in a PhD-holder's CV/Resume when he applies for a PostDoc position?

Comment: Is this a postdoc in a lab science?  Those are very different from postdocs in math.

Comment: @Kimball, Computer-based.

Comment: What does "computer-based" mean? Computer Science? Something like data analysis, possibly in a lab? Simulations, say in theoretical branches of natural sciences? Solvers and proof assistants, as in math? There's lots of stuff computers are used for.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, Computer simulation of proteins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the thing you look for (and reject when not found) in a PhD-holder's CV/Resume when he applies for a PostDoc position?

First, I look their ability to complete the project I have funding for their position.
This includes, hopefully obvious things, like their technical skills (e.g., methodologies, programming skills, writing), but also their ability to learn.
Almost no PhDs would have a match for my positions, so I know I will need to train them, which is actually a fair trade because a postdoc is a transactional relationship.
The postdoc learns new skills while getting paid a decent wage (I work for a government center, so in 2023, the minimum at my center is about $70,000 with full benefits or ~$85,000 for some contractor positions) and the postdoc solves my problem.
Their study system for their PhD is not as important as their ability to learn new systems.
I check these skills by looking at their CV, coursework, and checking with references.

Second, I look for soft skills.
Their ability to communicate and work with a team.
This includes presenting, but also "playing well with others".
The last thing I need or want is somebody who destroys relationships that have taken years to build.
Some skills appear on CVs such as presentations, but also outreach events.
For example, have you taught elementary kids about sciences on Saturdays in grad school?
Or, do you present to local civic groups?
Were you a schoolteacher before going to grad school?
Reference checks help as well for this point.
Lastly, the interview helps with somebody's ability to communicate and provides some insight into their personality and ability to work well with others.

Third, I look for the ability to ask new questions.
I give my postdocs the chance to develop their own side project.
This comes up via reference checks and the interview.
As one of the closing questions, I ask something like *given what we've talked about today, what is a question you might ask as your own research question?*
I don't care what the candidate specifically says, but I want to see a decent idea and passion to learn (I know their actual side project will change once they learn more).

Finally, I would make a small note of their writing skills in their cover letter and CV.
Small typos are okay, but glaring problems here can raise red flags.
For example, with your question, I would note you use antiquated English and assume the male pronoun ("he") for all applicants with your question.
Not a deal breaker, but this would raise a small red flag that I would look into more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a lot more information about the field... But generally speaking you need to match all the "essential criteria" of the job advert and possibly some of the "desirable criteria" in order to be competitive amongst applicants.

Shortlisting requires the candidate to fit the advertised criteria via a formal HR process in most places. If shortlisted you also need to present well at interview.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the majority of short postdoc positions (less than 2.5 years), often the Postdoc obtaining it will leave sooner because of another appointment or the likes.

They are expensive, kind of unreliable (and rightly so) but they can be very effective in fixing urgent issues/needs in both teaching and research aspects.

So the criteria is "the closer the formal fit of the candidate I am looking for to the position I described in the opening, the better".

Grants, projects get funded, contacts with the industry: extremely nice to have.

Publication track, awards, all the other rational and objective metrics (i.e. crap like H-index, total count of citations, number of years at MIT, etcetc): yeah, nice to have, but not necessary and often the way they are presented they meta-tell something about the candidate.

What really help, in case of a cynical supervisor, is if the postdoc has a decent publication under preparation that fits the supervisor interest. The cynical supervisor will smell the option of being co-author and will be quite proactive.

Comment: +1 ... Can't help but highlight ... smell the option of being co-author and will be quite proactive ... #tapinto